# Filtering VLOOKUP data

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, gs-vlookup

I have google spreadsheet, that in first sheet I have a BIG table with datas of many people (players).

[image: Normal spreadsheet]

VLOOKUP formula for D10 is like this: **=VLOOKUP(B1;bielak3!A:G;3;false)**

Data in table in columns C-M are from other sheets using a VLOOKUP function.
But I want to sort that data by a columns, but inside that table only. Table have 100 rows.

I'm using filter from above menu and I try to filter my table. This is result:

[image: Corrupted table]

Now mostly vlookup formulas are changed! 
VLOOKUP formula is now like this: **=VLOOKUP({};bielak3!A:G;3;false)**

There in no B1 reference, but there is {}. WHY?

Oddly is, that it isn't in every rows... some vlookup formulas are incorrupted.

Have somebody any explanation of this situation? Why I have characters "{}" instead of B1 reference?

Comment: Maybe you can share a copy link of your sheet? In such kind of situation its hard to guess problem. Have you tried adding $ to your cell refrences so it will be =VLOOKUP($B$1.......)

Comment: It seems adding $ is helpfull... Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an absolute range, by adding dollar like,

```
 =VLOOKUP($B$1.......)
```